# Create custom UI Button with 2 text colors?

Tags: swift, uibutton

I have a UIButton mock-up and I want to make the number red as the mock-up. can someone help me to how to do it?

[image]

```
func arrowRightButton(baseColor:UIColor){
    self.setTitleColor(baseColor, for: .normal)
    self.setTitleColor(baseColor.withAlphaComponent(0.3), for: .highlighted)

    guard let image = UIImage(named: "ArrowRight")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate) else
    {
        return
    }
    guard let imageHighlight = UIImage(named: "ArrowRight")?.alpha(0.3)?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate) else
    {
        return
    }

    self.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

    self.setImage(image, for: .normal)
    self.setImage(imageHighlight, for: .highlighted)
    self.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: self.bounds.size.width-image.size.width*1.5, bottom: 0, right: 0);
    self.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    self.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red:0.29, green:0.64, blue:0.80, alpha:1.0).cgColor
    self.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10,left: 0,bottom: 10,right: 0)
}
```

Comment: why down vote. I could not find a way to make button text have 2 colors?

Comment: Why don't you just create a custom `UIControl` instead of hacking `UIButton`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **`NSAttributedString`** to get that working.

**Example:**

```
let str = "5 Low Balances"
let attrStr = NSMutableAttributedString(string: str)
attrStr.addAttributes([.foregroundColor:UIColor.red, .font:UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20.0, weight: .bold)], range: (str as NSString).range(of: "5"))
attrStr.addAttributes([.foregroundColor:UIColor.black, .font:UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15.0, weight: .bold)], range: (str as NSString).range(of: "Low Balances"))
self.button.setAttributedTitle(attrStr, for: .normal)
```

In the above code, I've added `UIColor.red` as `foregroundColor` of `5` in the text `5 Low Balances`. You can add other `attributes` as well as per your requirement.